# How to solve ReferenceError - gtag is not defined for Karma Jasmine test?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a global variable in my Typescript file for  Google Analytics.

```
declare var gtag: any;
```

When I run ng test in my Angular Project it's showing following error.

> ReferenceError: gtag is not defined

Comment: Have you found any soluion.

Comment: @NinjaTurtle, if you are still looking for the answer, please see my answer below. This finally worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation :** Since you are using google tag manager, you have to define the gtag function somewhere. When you followed the tutorial from googleAnalytics they asked you to include some javascript code in your index.html. The problem is when you run your tests you create components without their parents, so the actual index.html file is never loaded neither the javascript code you added. You need to load that code before you run your tests.

**How to proceed :**
I'd advise you to export that content in a separate file,
then import that file into your index.html

```
<script src="assets/metrics/gtm.js"></script>
```

After this go into your Karma.conf.js and below frameworks :[...] add the following :

```
   files: [
      /* I put my file (containing javascript code) into that path, yours might change */
      { pattern: 'src/assets/**/gtm.js', included: true }
    ],
```

After this you should be good to simply restart your tests!
Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: This works... sort of... My tests would randomly still fail with the `ReferenceError: gtag is not defined` error and then if I refresh them they might either show it again or they might pass. It seems very unstable. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that worked for me. I added the following code in a javascript file called `src/assets/js/gtag.init.js`:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
```

I then added the path to this file in my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
files: [
    { pattern: 'src/assets/js/gtag.init.js', included: true }
]
```

Lastly, I added the path in my `angular.json` file under `tests:scripts`:

```
{
    "test": {
        "scripts": [
            'src/assets/js/gtag.init.js'
        ]
    }
}
```

This finally made my tests pass, and the error is no longer produced.